# Textarea displaying data from mysql database with headings

Tags: html, mysql, textarea

I wonder if anyone could help me out..I have a textarea (disabled) in which I want to display the headings "Name", "Type", "Dosage", "Time Interval", "Amount Collected" and "Date Of Entry" (all underlined if possible) and then underneath I want to display the relevant data from the mysql database based on the date that the user has selected. Any ideas? I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need a table inside textarea?

You can't, instead just create a div with fixed width/height and overflow: auto, put your table inside of it, apply some styling and it will look just the same as it would in textearea.